# Show Hide div with css only

Tags: javascript, css, xhtml

I'm trying to do a show / hide using css only, is that possible or does some type of jscript is needed? this is what i'm trying to do, when anyone one of the 4 div's are clicked the div for it below is shown.

```
    <div class="span3">
        <img src="an1.jpg" class="img-rounded" />
        <h3>AN1<br />1234</h3>
    </div>

    <div class="span3">
        <img src="an2.jpg" class="img-rounded" />
        <h3>AN2<br />1234</h3>
    </div>

    <div class="span3">
        <img src="an3.jpg" class="img-rounded" />
        <h3>AN3<br />1234</h3>
    </div>

    <div class="span3">
        <img src="an4.jpg" class="img-rounded" />
        <h3>AN4<br />1234</h3>
    </div>
```

Show div when div is click:

```
<div style="display: none;"> this is AN1 </div>
<div style="display: none;"> this is AN2 </div>
<div style="display: none;"> this is AN3 </div>
<div style="display: none;"> this is AN4 </div>
```

Comment: There are no click event handlers in CSS.

Comment: JQuery is must in this condition

Comment: You'll need jQuery or Javascript to bind click events.

Comment: You need javascript for this, if you want to use as little javascript as possible then handle all the show/hide elements with a css class and add/remove that class with javascript

Answer (score 12):

You can use a hidden input that can be toggled that corresponds to the label in the click area.

```
<div class="span3">
<label for="an1">
    <img src="an1.jpg" class="img-rounded" />
</label>
<h3><label for="an1">AN1<br />1234</label></h3>
</div>
...
<input id="an1" type=checkbox><div style="display: none;"> this is AN1 </div>
```

Then in your CSS:

```
[type=checkbox] {
    display: none;
}
:checked + div {
    display: block !important;
}
```

I would also stear clear of `style` and just use the stylesheet.

http://jsfiddle.net/ExplosionPIlls/ZyAXA/1/

Comment: +1 This is a great solution that I frequently use but it should be mentioned that it won't going to work in older browsers.

Comment: 1+ This is freaking genius!

Comment: @Alex what about it is hacked?

Comment: Maybe hacks to harsh, 'not intended for this use' is more like it i.e. 99.9% of the developer community dont use such trickery...

Comment: This technique requires a full awareness and understanding of how selectors work in modern browsers.  It is leading edge, but nothing wrong with that.  Why not innovate?  The one big advantage, it helps to minimize the amount of jQuery/JavaScript code required for a page.  I suspect that the CSS engine in modern browsers is quicker than the JavaScript interpreter, so we should take advantage of it when applicable.

Comment: Minor variation: http://jsfiddle.net/audetwebdesign/ZyAXA/2/ If you don't want to use an inline style, you can simply add a rule to hide the div.

Comment: this works in the demo for me, but soon as I added it to the site it stops working. it's bootstrap, i'm adding this to a site for someone but bootstrap is so bloated with css tags the simplest things require the use of !important... in which is still not helping

Comment: This is pretty terrible for accessibility. I agree that innovation is good, until it comes at the expense of non-visual users. Using an input element to show/hide content is really bad because it communicates the expectation of a form control to a user when that is not the purpose of the UI. Either use JavaScript for your toggle panel or find a more accessible solution.

Comment: @Marcy Sutton The checkbox is set to `display: none;`. Wouldn't that prevent screen readers from reporting it? In any case, the purpose of a checkbox is to indicate whether an option is selected or not, which is exactly what this checkbox is doing. If anything, a javascript-based solution would be even less informative to the vision-impaired user, I would think.

Comment: Yes, the checkbox being `display: none` means it is kept out of a screen reader. But that also means the interactive toggle control is kept from a keyboard or screen reader user--a label by itself is not an interactive element. This approach is unusable to anyone using a keyboard or screen reader.

Comment: @Marcy Sutton I believe all of the problems you've identified can be solved with a few minor modifications: [**demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/qgh2LxnL/1/)

Comment: @DoctorDestructo technically that does work (nice job!), but it is questionable whether you should use form inputs and labels to show/hide content. It is still a confusing implementation to someone using assistive technology.

Comment: @Marcy I guess I'm sort of on the fence about this approach. As a general rule, I try not to use javascript where CSS will suffice, but I can see how this technique could cause some confusion in a collaborative situation since a blind person would be "seeing" a different type of form control than a sighted person. In any case, it was a fun challenge trying to overcome your objections :)

Answer (score 7):

In most browsers you should simply use the `href` attribute of the `a` elements and an `id` for the element to show:

```
<a href="#div1">Div one</a>
<a href="#div2">Div two</a>
<a href="#div3">Div three</a>
<a href="#div4">Div four</a>

<div id="content">
    <div id="div1">This is div one</div>
    <div id="div2">This is div two</div>
    <div id="div3">This is div three</div>
    <div id="div4">This is div four</div>
</div>
```

Coupled with the CSS:

```
#content > div {
    display: none;
}

#content > div:target {
    display: block;
}
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/x8HmQ/).

In the HTML the wrapper `div` (`#content`) isn't necessary, it's simply to make it easier to specifically target those elements it contains (you could, of course, simply use a `class` instead).

To add hiding functionality (to hide *all*, rather than just hide the sibling `div`s when showing another), unfortunately requires a link to trigger a hash-change (in order to stop the `:target` selector matching the `div`s), which in turn requires a link (either in each of the `div`s to show or elsewhere in the document, either linking elswhere (as follows):

```
<ul id="andHideAgain">
    <li><a href="#div1">Div one</a></li>
    <li><a href="#div2">Div two</a></li>
    <li><a href="#div3">Div three</a></li>
    <li><a href="#div4">Div four</a></li>
</ul>

<div id="content">
    <div id="div1">This is div one <a class="hide" href="#andHideAgain">hide</a></div>
    <div id="div2">This is div two <a class="hide" href="#andHideAgain">hide</a></div>
    <div id="div3">This is div three <a class="hide" href="#andHideAgain">hide</a></div>
    <div id="div4">This is div four <a class="hide" href="#andHideAgain">hide</a></div>
</div>
```

[JS Fiddle demo (link in each `div`)](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/x8HmQ/1/).

Or the simple use of just a hash:

- Div one
- Div two
- Div three
- Div four
- hide

```
<div id="content">
    <div id="div1">This is div one</div>
    <div id="div2">This is div two</div>
    <div id="div3">This is div three</div>
    <div id="div4">This is div four</div>
</div>
```

[JS Fiddle demo (using a single `a`, and an 'empty' hash)](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/x8HmQ/2/).

Comment: Gosh. @DavidThomas You already answered it before me. Ah, just saw after posting the answer. I was getting one new answer, but was wondering that let me post it first, then I shall see it. You deserved it first. +1 from me.

Comment: @Nathan: it's okay, dupe answers aren't necessarily a bad thing, and you don't have to explain or excuse yourself. =)

Answer (score 4):

this is how i solve show hide problem with just

here is my div with its class declared

```
 <div class='loading'> </div>
```

and here is the javascript that

```
$('.loading').hide();
```

and

```
$('.loading').css("display", "block");
```